# Excel conditional formatting for finding duplicates

Tags: excel, duplicates, conditional-formatting

I'm struggling with applying conditional formatting in Excel.

I'm searching for duplicates, am comparing A2 with A1, A3 with A2... and in case a duplicate is found, I would like to color second line red, as it's obvious from the screenshot:

[image]

If I apply the generally advised formula `=A2=A1`, it would color the first of the two duplicates, which is wrong (as I would like to color the second one, the only I'm likely to delete).

I can definitely solve this with a formula that produces X in new column (Row1 is blank, on Row2 `=IF(A2=A1,X,"")`, but I would like to solve this visually as it's crucial for manual inspection.

If I apply the formula `=A2<>A1`, everything else apart from the desired field gets selected: 
[image]

Thank you.
Mat

Comment: Does your Applies To range have to start at row 1?  if not, change that to `$L$2:$L23` and keep your exisiting formula `=L2=L1`

Comment: Chris, thank you so much. I never thought of it that way. I have to assume first entry is unique in order for this to work, you are indeed correct - it works as designed.